# How can document-based settings be stored?

Tags: swift, macos, core-data

I have a Core Data, document-based, storyboard-backed, OS X project. Each document will have a specific calendar year and province/state it's operating in, so I made a Settings entity that asks for these values when the document is created. Since certain behaviours are based on these Settings, other custom NSManagedObject classes need to ask for them, and it doesn't seem right to execute an NSFetchRequest every time I need the value. However, I'm not sure where to copy the values to, outside Core Data.

1. AppDelegate - as far as I'm aware, there's only one per application, not per document, so this won't be appropriate.
2. Document - this seems best, but I'm not sure how to find the document again later, from inside an NSManagedObject. I tried defining a var year inside Document, then from the NSManagedObject calling theWindow.controller?.document?.year, but theWindow is nil if I don't set it myself. Also, theWindow is global, outside AppDelegate, so even if I do define it (in Document's makeWindowControllers() by theWindow = windowController.window), it again becomes per-app, so every time I call this line, I'm finding the year of the last-opened document (the last one to overwrite theWindow), not the active document. I'm not sure how to find a reference to the current window.
3. User Defaults - again, this is per-app, not per-document. My current solution uses these defaults, then redefines the defaults (with an NSFetchRequest) every time windowDidBecomeMain is called, so the current Document sets the User Defaults to its own Settings.

It seems unlikely I'm the only one to want settings per-document, but I can't seem to find any examples or previous questions on how/where to define these. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're describing per-document metadata, and fortunately Core Data supports this kind of metadata. Each persistent store file (which is what `NSPersistentDocument` uses) can have its own metadata dictionary with whatever keys and values you need. It's kind of like user defaults except that it's part of the document. This data is part of the file but separate from the SQLite store that makes up the actual document data.

The metadata API is on `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. You get your coordinator in a document via `self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator`. There are a few methods there to read and write the document metadata. Save your year and province/state in the metadata, and then look it up and consult it when opening a document.

Core Data has its own metadata that you don't want to lose-- so when editing metadata, make sure to look up the existing metadata, modify it, and save the new data.  Don't just assign a completely new metadata dictionary to the document.

Comment: You're beautiful! Can't believe I didn't get this from any of my readings before on Core Data. Couldn't figure out how to migrate previous entities into the metadata, so a warning to users to update the couple of values on first run of the update will have to suffice. Otherwise it looks like it'll work perfectly. A note to others: don't forget `managedObjectContext.save()` after the `.setMetadata(:forPersistentStore:)`, or it won't take.

Comment: Correction: `managedObjectContext.save()` will result in an alert to the user that the document was changed by another application, and options to "Save anyway" or "Revert". It seems safer to call `saveDocument(nil)`, and let the document save the store, or even better, call `updateChangeCount(.ChangeDone)` and let autosave do the work for you, when it's ready.